# What's the difference between "happen to be" and "used to be"?

Tags: phrases

Can they be used interchangeably in following example?

> Put that thing back where it used to be.
>   Put that thing back where it happen to be.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not.

*Where it used to be* = where it was in the past.

If something *happens to be* in a particular place, it is there by chance. You can't put it *back* there, because it is there already!